# eclipse rcp: custom popup menu behavior (2-way popup menu)

Tags: popup, eclipse-rcp, popupmenu

I would like to ask your advise on the following:

I'd like to change the default behavior of popup menus, so that first a custom pre-popup will show up with some menu-items -- one of the items will open the default popup, but the rest will be dynamic, based on selected objects (there will be few of them).

What I've already tried:

- implemented custom **MenuManager** to insert custom defined menus
- implemented custom **MenuSourceProvider** to control **menuAboutToShow** (thus replace/reorder menu items)
- extended schema to define custom menu (still using command framework and **IConfigurationElement**)

This is still a "half-solution" as I'm not getting 2-way-popup menus (a pre-popup menu and then, if needed, the default popup).

Can you please provide some hints on this?

Thank you in advance.